# How to segment away the skull from the brain in MRI image

Tags: matlab

I have been given a data set consisting of image slizes from a MRI scan of a brain. With these images, I am to remove the skull, so that only the brain remains. Are there any good segmentation techniques that can be used on these types of images?

[image: brain]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the skull is always on the outside of the image, and it's always well-separated from the brain.

## Approach 1: First principles

Draw a line across the centre of the image and stop when you find the first white pixel - this will be part of the skull. Find all pixels connected to that pixel. Remove them and you are left with the brain.

## Approach 2: Use the image processing toolbox

This is the "connected components segmentation" problem. MATLAB's image processing toolbox has a `bwconncomp()` function that enumerates connected components in a black and white image. [See this tutorial](http://au.mathworks.com/help/images/image-enhancement-and-analysis.html) about how to count grains of rice in a photo - very similar problem.

Comment: the link to the tutorial is broke, can you fix it please.

Answer (score 0):

SPM8 (Statistical Parametric Mapping) is a neuroimaging software that is free but requires MATLAB. It can be programmed using MATLAB and it has "Segment" function that you can use to separate gray matter, white matter and cerebrospinal fluid from the rest. With SPM8 you can also realign your images and normalize them to match some template image etc., if you wish to do so, and a lot of other things, depending on if you have anatomical or functional MR images, or both.

FSL (FMRIB Software Library) is a free alternative (no MATLAB required, can be programmed using Python) and it also has segmentation function and a lot of other functions.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use SPM for Skull stripping 
https://www.nitrc.org/projects/mrtool/

Applying segmentation to your structural volume will generate a number of masks (files named c#filename.nii) indicating the different tissues of interest.

To perform skull-stripping keeping 3 classes of the grey-matter, white-matter, and CSF (masks c1.nii to c3.nii) and remove the rests. after segmentation simply using SPM 'imcalc' option and multiplying your original structural volume by the sum of these masks.

ANTs:
https://github.com/ANTsX/ANTs/blob/master/Scripts/antsBrainExtraction.sh

First, you will need to have the antsBrainExtraction.sh script to run the brain extraction. You may find it in the  you cloned on the installation step. If you used the binary files, it probably won’t be there. Therefore, you will need to create an empty file called antsBrainExtraction.sh. Now go here, copy all the code to your file and save it. In any case you should end up with the shell script for the brain extraction.

Second, you will need to have a template to perform the brain extraction. Dr. Gorgolewski recommended OASIS. Go ahead and download it from here. Other templates will work too, but it’s up to you to find out which one works the best with your data.

Now we are ready to do the brain extraction itself. Actually, it’s quite simple. All you need is to run the following from your bash terminal:

antsBrainExtraction.sh -d  -a  \
-e  -m  -o

3DSlicer, newest version: 
https://www.slicer.org/wiki/Modules:SkullStripperModule

ANTs and slicer use similar method by the way. Let me know if you have further questions

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.